# How to trigger action prop on Antd form with NextJS 13?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, antd, next.js13

I recenlty use NextJS 13 and I want to use the server actions feature. To achivie this, I created 2 components:

`login-form-server.tsx`

```
import { revalidatePath } from 'next/cache';
import { cookies } from 'next/headers';
import LoginFormClient from './login-form-client';
import { redirect } from 'next/navigation';

export default function LoginForm() {
  async function updateItem(data: FormData) {
    'use server';
    console.log('Success:', data);
    const response = await fetch('http://localhost:4001/users/sign-in', {
      method: 'POST',
      body: JSON.stringify(Object.fromEntries(data)),
      headers: {
        'Content-type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
      },
    });
    const responseParsed = await response.json();
    console.log(responseParsed);
    cookies().set('token', responseParsed.token);
    revalidatePath('/');
    redirect('/');
  }

  return <LoginFormClient updateItem={updateItem} />;
}
```

and `login-form-client.tsx`:

```
'use client';
import { Button, Form, Input } from 'antd';

type Props = {
  updateItem: (data: FormData) => Promise<void>;
};
export default function LoginFormClient({ updateItem }: Props) {

  type FieldType = {
    email?: string;
    password?: string;
    remember?: string;
  };

  return (
    <main>
      {/* with this works ===>      <form action={updateItem}>
        <input type="text" name="email" />
        <input type="password" name="password" />
        <hr />
        <button type="submit">Update Item</button>
      </form> */}
      <Form
        action={updateItem}
        name="basic"
        labelCol={{ span: 8 }}
        wrapperCol={{ span: 16 }}
        style={{ maxWidth: 600, marginTop: 100 }}
        initialValues={{ remember: true }}
        // onFinish={onFinish}
        // onFinishFailed={onFinishFailed}
        autoComplete="off"
      >
        <Form.Item<FieldType>
          label="Email"
          name="email"
          rules={[{ required: true, message: 'Please input your email!' }]}
        >
          <Input />
        </Form.Item>

        <Form.Item<FieldType>
          label="Password"
          name="password"
          rules={[{ required: true, message: 'Please input your password!' }]}
        >
          <Input.Password />
        </Form.Item>

        <Form.Item<FieldType>
          name="remember"
          valuePropName="checked"
          wrapperCol={{ offset: 8, span: 16 }}
        ></Form.Item>

        <Form.Item wrapperCol={{ offset: 8, span: 16 }}>
          <Button type="primary" htmlType="submit">
            Submit
          </Button>
        </Form.Item>
      </Form>
    </main>
  );
}
```

Using a pure html `form` this code works. But when I swith to Antd Form component, nothings happen. Can enybody help me to solve this? Thanks!

Comment: `onFinish` event is commented, you should use it to handle form submit event, it's equivalent to `action` on pure html form. You should also remove `action` prop from Form component.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `onFinish` prop to pass your server action instead, as your component `LoginFormClient` is already a client component it should do the job.

```
<Form
        name="basic"
        labelCol={{ span: 8 }}
        wrapperCol={{ span: 16 }}
        style={{ maxWidth: 600, marginTop: 100 }}
        initialValues={{ remember: true }}
        onFinish={updateItem}
        autoComplete="off"
      >
    {/* form content */}
</Form>
```

You'll have to change your server action to handle `onFinish` callback arguments instead of formData.

```
export default function LoginForm() {
  async function updateItem(data: FieldType) {
    'use server';
    console.log('Success:', data);
    const response = await fetch('http://localhost:4001/users/sign-in', {
      method: 'POST',
      body: JSON.stringify(data),
      headers: {
        'Content-type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
      },
    });
    const responseParsed = await response.json();
    console.log(responseParsed);
    cookies().set('token', responseParsed.token);
    revalidatePath('/');
    redirect('/');
  }

  return <LoginFormClient updateItem={updateItem} />;
}
```

Also fyi you can define your server action in its own file with `"use server";` at the top then use it directly in `LoginFormClient` by importing it instead of passing it via props from `LoginForm`.

Comment: This is a cool solution... but, how if I need to disable the fields and submit button while we are doing the fetch? Also, in case of error, we must show an notification to user and show it "User or password incorrect"... how we can handle that on this sample? Thanks a lot!

Comment: This is a different subject, even if you were using an html form you'll have the same issue (loading, error). This is actually discussed by the nextjs team and on GH but for now there's no (satisfying) solution to do that in full server components. But as you're already in client component you can use the returned values from you server actions to set errors and `useTransition` to handle loading state. See nextjs docs & repo discussions for more infos about that subject.